# wkhtmltopdf doesn't execute associated javascript when creating a pdf from webpage

Tags: javascript, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from command line and am trying to create a pdf from a webpage. The webpage content is updated once a day and filled with current information by javascript.
When I use wkthmltopdf it renders all the "bare"/"empty" HTML but without current information included by the javascript, as if the javascript has not yet been loaded for the PDF or just ignored.

I am using  `wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 60000 --no-stop-slow-scripts --enable-javascript https://example.com/ test.pdf` 
Do you know how to create the pdf after the javascript has been loaded and filled the webpage with current information?

Comment: try to debug javascript.
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151755/debugging-javascript-in-wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, actually it seems like it was a minor problem in my javascript. The debugging showed a SyntaxError: (Parse error). Previously I used for ... of in the javascript and now changed to a for .. in loop, which seems to have solved the problem. Though I don't quite understand why this solved the problem?

Comment: for of is ES6 (javascript version), wkhtmltopdf probably use ES5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

After debugging the javascript via wkhtmltopdf (added option --debug-javascript) as @Nitin suggested I found that I had a SyntaxError (parse error).

I changed parts of the javascript  from a "for..of" to "for..in" loop. This solved the problem an the pdf was created correctly. Thanks @Daphoque for explaining that this is probably due to the javascript version used by wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this with jquery, but it was working fine with vanilla js.
Are you using javascript library ?

Comment: I use '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>'. However please see my comment above I seem to have solved the problem by changing a minor piece of code in the javascript. I am surprised this actually helped..