# Javascript not completely running in PDF

Tags: javascript, html, wkhtmltopdf

I have a HTML page with a table on it (attached to this)

I am trying to hide one of the columns at runtime. I know the JS is firing as I am outputting some text to the page and thats working (see div id `poo`)

https://pastebin.com/iqMnYGgu   <-- html here

If I open the page in a browser, the JS works as expected, but for some reason the wkhtmltopdf binary doesn't seem to like it

Wonder if its a problem with qt but how do I test that?

The `wkhtmtopdf` command line I am using is:

```
# wkhtmltopdf-amd64 \
   --encoding UTF-8 \
   --margin-top 10 \
   --margin-right 10 \
   --margin-bottom 25 \
   --margin-left 10 \
   --page-size A4 \
   --orientation portrait \
   --dpi 300 \
   --zoom 0.9 \
   --header-spacing 30 \
   --no-outline \
   --no-stop-slow-scripts \
   --disable-smart-shrinking \
   --javascript-delay 5000 \
   --debug-javascript /tmp_wkhtmlto_pdf_XlMAtk.html \
   output.pdf
```

Any advise on how to debug this?

I've stayed away from jquery and have gone for vanilla JS which I thought would be better for all concerned.

Here is a visual description of the issue:

[image]

Comment: There seem to be some extra closing `div` tags. That might be the crucial point here

Comment: See https://ctrl.vi/i/YOD3qFHs4 for details

Comment: Its not that. They are simply left over from when I anonymised the real page for this post.

Comment: I've removed those, and same issue

Comment: What does you debugging output tell you (you gave the command line parameter `--debug-javascript /tmp_wkhtmlto_pdf_XlMAtk.html` )?

Comment: I pasted your code to a codepen. https://codepen.io/yunzen/pen/VwdELZV/3efaca2f58235cc40e46859e5ff1a75d. The JS code doesn't work there either

Comment: Your attribute quotes are weird. Sometimes you have something like this `<tag attr='single quotes then double single quotes''>`

Comment: The js works in the codepen. It only has to hide the totals. Which it has done, but it should also remove the total <th> - which it used to do before I started debugging\

Comment: The JS does not work WITHOUT ERROR. Look at the console log!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151755/debugging-javascript-in-wkhtmltopdf

Comment: It seems as if the QtWeb Browser, which does the browsing part behind the scenes in wkhtmltopdf, doesn't support removing HTMLElements with the `remove` method (I got no reference for this, but this stems from testing).   
  
Try replacing every `.remove()` with `.outerHTML = ""`

Comment: Or use the polyfill from here: https://github.com/chenzhenxi/element-remove/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is related to the very old (2013) browser which is the behind-the-scenes HTML/CSS/JS-Interpreter of `wkhtmltopdf`. This browser is the [QtWeb](http://www.qtweb.net/) browser, which last update dates from September 2013. The QtWeb browser uses the AppleWebKit 534.34 engine, which [dates back to 2011](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/tags/Safari-534.34).

The support for [`Element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) in Safari browsers seems to have only been [integrated as soon as October 2013](https://caniuse.com/?search=remove).

Therefore it is save to assume there is no support for `Element.remove()` in `wkhtmltopdf`.

You have several alternatives at hand.

1. Use `targetElement.outerHTML = ''` instead of `targetElement.remove()`
2. Use `targetElement.parentElement.removeChild(targetElement)` instead of `targetElement.remove()`
3. Keep using `targetElement.remove()`, but insert this [polyfill](https://github.com/chenzhenxi/element-remove) before

```
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('remove')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'remove', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function remove() {
        this.parentNode && this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, CharacterData.prototype, DocumentType.prototype].filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: You legend. Thanks. I knew it was an issue with qt (I did say that in the post) but I couldn't work out how to test it.

Comment: You can install the QtWeb browser on your computer to test it

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find the download link on their site!

Comment: @Chris It's at the top right in the blue main menu

Answer (score 0):

Try follwing JS code:

I added an assertion that the respective `targetElement` exists before trying to remove it.

```
if (targetElements) {
   // ...
}
```

```
function sortOutTotals() {
  document.getElementById("poo").textContent = "something here";
  var masterElement = document.getElementsByClassName(
    "ceta_row_quote_section_detail"
  );

  for (var i = 0; i < masterElement.length; i++) {
    var subElement = masterElement[i];
    var targetElement = subElement.querySelector("td[data-col='quotedtotal']");
    console.log(targetElement.textContent);
    if (targetElement) {
      targetElement.remove();
      targetElement.textContent = "poo";
    }
  }

  var masterElement = document.getElementsByClassName(
    "ceta_row_quote_section_detail"
  );
  for (var i = 0; i < masterElement.length; i++) {
    var subElement = masterElement[i];
    var targetElement = subElement.querySelector("td[data-col='description']");
    if (targetElement) {
      targetElement.colSpan = 2;
    }
  }

  var masterElement = document.getElementsByClassName(
    "ceta_row_quote_column_headings"
  );
  for (var i = 0; i < masterElement.length; i++) {
    var subElement = masterElement[i];
    var targetElement = subElement.querySelector("th[data-col='quotedtotal']");
    if (targetElement) {
      targetElement.remove();
    }
  }

  var masterElement = document.getElementsByClassName(
    "ceta_row_quote_column_headings"
  );
  for (var i = 0; i < masterElement.length; i++) {
    var subElement = masterElement[i];
    var targetElement = subElement.querySelector("th[data-col='description']");
    if (targetElement) {
      targetElement.colSpan = 2;
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function (e) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    sortOutTotals();
  }, 10000);
};
```

Also you have got some flaws in your HTML code. Some attributes are wrong and you have extra whitespace in some `data-col` attributes, which is not automatically accounted for in JS.

For example:
This:
`<th class='ceta_cell_heading ceta_data_type_text'' data-col=' description'>Description</th>`
Should be:
`<th class='ceta_cell_heading ceta_data_type_text' data-col='description'>Description</th>`
`------------------------------------------------^----------^`

If you are not able the format the `data-col` values without the whitespace try to change the selector query code from `"th[data-col='quotedtotal']"` to `"th[data-col*='quotedtotal']"` (added the asterisk `*` before the equals sign)

Comment: Good spot on the data attributes. I fixed that and added the assertion, but it didn't help. I'm not sure how the assertion would help me, but I willing to try anything at the moment